# When can I see the Giant Waves in Nazare, Portugal?

Tags: nature-and-wildlife, atlantic-ocean

I know that the waves hitting the Portuguese coast are the result of larger storms in the Atlantic Ocean.

Whenever the forecast predicts large waves and I have the chance I go to Nazare to see those large waves. Unfortunately quite often the Nazare waves are not considerable bigger than on any other beach along the coast. How comes that only sometimes those waves get really huge there? When is the best best time of the year to experience this phenomenon?

[image]

<sub>note: I took this photo on the 11th of December, 2014.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How comes that only sometimes those waves get really huge there?

Several factors are needed for the waves to get really huge there, which only happens from time to time.

From https://nazarewaves.com/en/Home/InfoNorthCanyon: "The Nazare North Canyon is the main responsible for the generation of the big waves at Nazare, Portugal, in conjunction with other nature elements, sometimes in a favorable way, like the big Atlantic Ocean swells, the collision of two waves directions, the wind, the tides, the sea currents and sea floor."

> When is the best best time of the year to experience this phenomenon?

From [nazarewaves.com](https://nazarewaves.com/en/Home/InfoForTourists#:%7E:text=When%20to%20go%20and%20for,see%20the%20Nazare%20big%20waves.):

> The Big Waves season in Nazare - Portugal, is between **October and March** (winter season in Portugal, but September and April also work in some years). So that is the best time to see the Nazare big waves. For those who need to book the trip in advance, a stay of at least 2 weeks in the region is recommended to ensure that you catch at least one day of giant waves; a three week stay increases the chances of catching big waves days.

One may view the wave height forecast on https://nazarewaves.com/en/webcams#divAfterWebCam1:

[image]

[nazarewaves.com](https://nazarewaves.com/en/Home/InfoForTourists#:%7E:text=When%20to%20go%20and%20for,see%20the%20Nazare%20big%20waves.) mentions:

> It is not possible to know more than a week in advance the forecast of the waves and the forecast may fail.

(even though they predict for the next 10 days.)

Note that on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_surfing_records, the top 3 highest surfed waves in Nazare occurred in November or close to it.

Comment: *Several factors are needed for the waves to get really huge there, which only happens from time to time*. @Franck: Any ideas what those factors are?

Comment: @Vickel e.g., sea storms. From https://nazarewaves.com/en/Home/InfoNorthCanyon: "The Nazare North Canyon is the main responsible for the generation of the big waves at Nazare, Portugal, in conjunction with other nature elements, sometimes in a favorable way, like the big Atlantic Ocean swells, the collision of two waves directions, the wind, the tides, the sea currents and sea floor."